# CSS mobile "snap" effect while swiping/scrolling?

Tags: css, scroll

I'm wondering if there's some way to use CSS (or JavaScript if I have to) to have a "snap" or "detent" effect on mobile.

To elaborate: if I have a div that has `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` set on it, I'd like a way so that when the user swipes, it will stick or snap to certain child divs within that div. So if a user is scrolling through products, for example, they can't possibly wind up in a spot where they are scrolled in between two products. It will always snap to a product.

The only thing I've found so far that *might* do this is [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/), but I was wondering if there was some clever secret CSS way to do this. Or if not, any other JS options I might have.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no simple snippet to achieve that. I prefer [zynga's scroller library](https://github.com/zynga/scroller) for that feature. But [this one](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) also has a bunch of stars on GitHub.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to adjust the scroll position with CSS alone. You'll have to seek out a JS lib to do it.